# PHP registration page, stopping duplicate submissions

Tags: php, html, authentication, registration

I am making a PHP Registration page for my website, and I am currently using this code below for the action of the registration form. Currently if you refresh the page, after you submit data into the database, it will resubmit. I know how to use a header redirect, and I will also use that. Although I am wanting to make it to where if there is another user with the same username, to make the script not submit into the database. How would I go upon doing this with a IF function?

```
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';
$birth_year= $_POST['year'];
$birth_month= $_POST['month'];
$birth_day= $_POST['day'];
$birthday=$_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day'];
$password=md5($_POST['password']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO users      (first_name,last_name,username,password,email,gender,birthday) VALUES (:first_name,:last_name,:username,:password,:email,:gender,:birthday)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':first_name'=>$_POST['first_name'],
          ':last_name'=>$_POST['last_name'],
          ':username'=>$_POST['username'],
          ':password'=>$password,
          ':email'=>$_POST['email'],
          ':gender'=>$_POST['gender'],
          ':birthday'=>$birthday));
?>
```

Comment: @UnholyRanger What does that change?

Comment: A `unique index` will prevent multiple rows having the same value. So if user A has username: alpha and user B trys to use that, the insert will fail. This also will prevent a resubmission (not fully, but to the DB)

Comment: @unholyranger Okay, thats good! But how would I display that to the user?

Answer (score 2):

Get a count of rows where `username=$_POST['username']`:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$checkexisting = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=:username");

if($checkexisting->execute(array(':username' => $username))->fetchColumn() == 0) {
  // username does not exist
  // fetch column returns the first column from the select statement, which is COUNT(*)
}
```

Or make the username column a unique ID.  This will prevent any duplicate values for this column directly in the database.  You have to be prepared for your SQL statements to throw an error then.

Also to help with refreshing and not resubmitting the form, look at John's answer with POST/REDIRECT/GET.

Comment: Wait so where would the query go? If you don't mind make a jsfiddle of that in my code? That would be great.

Comment: The query is executed in the if conditional.  If the count of `$username`'s in the database is 0, then you want to continue inserting the user.  So the final `INSERT` statement would go in between the conditional.

Answer (score 1):

A script will not "submit into the database". Your script will run a query to try to INSERT a row into the database. If username is to be unique, then make it a unique index and the SQL INSERT statement will fail and return you a code telling you that that particular entry already exists.

Comment: So if I make the username a unique, it will prevent another account with the same user name? How would I display this to a user?

Comment: As you have asked it, the answer is: echo 'This username is already in use'; but I can't believe that that was what you wanted to ask. Can you expand your question?

Comment: well with the unique, it wouldn't allow duplicate usernames. But what would the code for the error be? Like how would my code know when to display that?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, "the SQL INSERT statement will fail and return you a code telling you that that particular entry already exists". In fact you would get a 1062 error code returned. When you detect that you know that there was already an entry for that index item. Search for "mysql 1062" for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Pages that are loaded via POST will cause the browser to ask the user to resubmit the information to view the page resulting in the actions performed by that page happening again.

The best to work around this is to use the [POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern](http://www.andypemberton.com/engineering/the-post-redirect-get-pattern/). I used it in an example about [processing payments that I wrote for Authorize.Net](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Handling-Online-Payments-Part-6-Preventing-Duplicate-Submissions/ba-p/11168). Hopefully that points you in the right direction.